# Using percent signs (%) in echo statement on same line as IF conditional check of variable

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

I'm trying to use this line in a batch file

```
If NOT "%1%"=="foo" (echo %bar% Text. >> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Log File.txt")
```

and when I run it I get this

```
) was unexpected at this time.

C:\>      If NOT "ARGUMENTBARUSERPROFILE\Desktop\Log File.txt")
```

(ARGUMENT = whatever argument/parameter I used when running the batch file)

I've tried all sorts of variations, including changing "Log File.txt" to "LogFile.txt" and removing the quotes around the path, and have narrowed it down to the fact it breaks whenever there's a `%` sign (from trying to echo a variable) or a colon (from the path to the right of the `>>`). I have no idea what the colon issue is, but the `%` one seems like it's being greedy and reading the line to mean that the variable being tested is the entire concatenated string of all contents enclosed by a `%` pair plus the rest of the line (presumably because there's no operator after so it just keeps going until EOL, where it runs into the parenthesis). So it seems either something needs to be escaped, there's something else I need to change, or it's just not possible.

I realize I could simply put the echo statement on another line like this

```
If NOT... (
  echo...
)
```

but I'd rather do it on one line, partly because it's cleaner, but mostly just because I'm curious and like to figure stuff like this out, and I hate when I can't.

BTW, delayed expression is enabled.

EDIT: Based on @AFH's comment, I tested it in a batch file on its own and discovered that this

```
@echo on
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
SET bar=test
If NOT "%1%"=="foo" (echo %bar% Text. >> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Log File.txt")
```

doesn't give the error but putting *anything* after it (e.g., `endlocal` on the next line or even a blank next line) does. ***However***, using `%1` instead of `%1%`, as mentioned by ADH, did fix it, so that was the problem. Therefore this is solved.

Comment: I can't reproduce this error on Win10, but it's worth pointing out that the first parameter to a batch file is `%1`, not `%1%`, though neither form gave your error.

Comment: Thanks. I did some more testing based on your comment and edited the question. EDIT: And I just realized I still left it as %1%, changing it to %1 does fix it. So it was actually the double %'s doing it, you probably just didn't see it because I'm guessing you didn't have any lines after. So you could provide that as the solution if you want and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it's fixed. [Scott's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1415192/327367) covers the explanation in excellent detail, and I have nothing to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t been able to reproduce your exact error,
but I can confirm [AFH’s observation](https://superuser.com/q/1415166/150988#comment2136274_1415166) that command-line parameters
are `%n` (e.g., `%1`, `%2`, etc.)
and not `%n%`, so your command should be

```
If NOT "%1"=="foo" (echo %bar% Text. >> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Log File.txt")
```

I believe that I can shed some light on what happens
when you include the extra `%`. 
CMD seems to parse command lines for parameters and variables
before doing anything else, and it uses a very simple-minded parser. 
When it encounters a `%`,

- if the next character is a digit,
  then it’s a `%n` positional parameter;
- if it’s anything else, it’s a variable (`%name%`),
  and *everything* up to the next `%` is the *`name`*. 
  I guess it gets really confused if there isn’t a matching `%`.

So here’s how your command is parsed:

```
If NOT "%1%"=="foo" (echo %bar% Text. >> "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Log File.txt")
        \/\---------------/   \-----------/           \---------------------- ...?
```

It thinks that `"=="foo" (echo`  and  `Text. >> "` are variable names,
while `bar` and `USERPROFILE` is literal text. 
For example,
running your command with an argument of “hello” yielded this error message
that is similar to what you got:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
 
C:(current directory)>            If NOT "hellobarUSERPROFILE\Desktop\Log File.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks! While I already had it figured out thanks to AFH, this explanation was really helpful to see _why_ it was happening. The amount of wasted time due to a single % sign...